# Minecraft 1.8: Check if player is at a specific Y position

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can you tell me if it is **possible** to use the `testfor` command to check if a player stands on a specific **Y** position?

I tried it with 
`/testfor @e[type=Player] {Pos:{Y:57d}}`, but it won't work.

The error was `[Player] did not match the required data structure`

Comment: What do you mean by 'it won't work'? Can you give the specific error message that the command block throws?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms I'm guessing he means his code just doesn't give anything. (and so doesn't work)

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms The command block says `my_username did not match the required data structure` and the connected comparator does not power. Even if my height matches with the command.

Comment: Try using __/testfor @p {Pos:{<pos>}}__ I don't know if this will work, as I haven't done much with __/testfor__

Answer (score 1):

Use `@p[y=<y value>]`, replacing  with the y coordinate you wish to search.

Additionally, you can define a cubic search area with `@p[x=<x value>,y=<y value>,z=<z value>]`, replacing `<x value>, <y value>, and <z value>` with their respective values.

Do not put spaces after the commas. For more information, visit:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_Block https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands